# Как сконфигурировать apache?

Tags: apache

Столкнулся с проблемой при конфигурации апача, проблема с virtualhost.
Прописал два домена, при переходе по IP сервера попадаю на один из доменов, а хотелось бы на отдельную директорию с алиасам на phpmyadmin. Как быть?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: @ifursov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно помню, в качестве сервера по умолчанию идет тот конфиг, который идет первым в листинге директории. Т.е. нужно назвать виртуалхост phpmyadmin так, чтобы он оказася первым в листинге, обычно называют 000-xxxx.conf